# Wix doesn't create the database

Tags: wix

Hi I need to use Wix to execute some sql script but it seems the database is not created. After I made the installer and installed it. I didn't get any error and couldn't see anything wrong in the log file also. However, I can't find the database created anywhere. I even tried a simple example from online and got the same thing. I obviously did something wrong. I am suspicious it was the username and password.  Here is the wxs file. The sql file is just some simple scripts to create a table. I hard coded the username, password and server name in it just to see if it works but it still doesn't.

The log file is like this:

MSI (s) (54!80) [17:47:12:108]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1505) of type 790531 for thread 12672
CreateDatabase:  Error 0x80004005: failed to create to database: 'EasyLobby11', error: unknown error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' xmlns:sql='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension'>
  <Product Name='Foobar 1.0' Id='YOURGUID-86C7-4D14-AEC0-86416A69ABDE' UpgradeCode='YOURGUID-7349-453F-94F6-BCB5110BA4FD'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'>

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installer"      
      InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installation [1]" />

    <util:User Id='SQLUser' Name='[SQLUSER]' Password='[SQLPASSWORD]' />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='InstallDir' Name='Acme'>

          <Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='YOURGUID-D8C7-4102-BA84-9702188FA316' KeyPath='yes'>

            <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='Foobar' User='SQLUser' Server='[SQLSERVER]'
              CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='yes' ContinueOnError='yes'>
              <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTable' BinaryKey='CreateTable' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Binary Id='CreateTable' SourceFile='CreateTable.sql' />

    <Feature Id='SqlFeature' Title='SqlFeature' Level='1'>
      <ComponentRef Id='SqlComponent' />
    </Feature>

    <Property Id='SQLUSER'>username</Property>
    <Property Id='SQLPASSWORD'>password</Property>
    <Property Id='SQLSERVER'>server</Property>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Found out the error is "Access Denied". I took out the User from SqlDatabase it then went fine.